# How to subset rows based on the first column?

Tags: python, r, subset

Okay this is a very naive question. I am trying to learn R. I have a big dataframe 20000 rows and 52 variables. I want to subset some of the entire rows based on the first column (gene names). In python, I would simply write:

```
for line in mydf:
  if line.startswith(TP53): ##name of a gene as an example
     print line.strip()
```

But how can I ask R to go through each line in a dataframe?
Sorry for the stupid question and thanks for your help

Comment: `mydf[mydf$my_first_column == "TP53", ]` ? Also easy to read solutions with `dplyr` package

Comment: `mydf[substr(mydf$gene,1,4)=="TP53",]` or something - you should read "An Introduction to R" to find out more about subsetting

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help